# how to search for a word in a chapter of a book stored in the database?

Tags: sql-server, search, full-text-search

I was trying to develop an application that searches through a book and lists out all the pages and lines that contain a given keyword or phrase.

Currently, I have split almost `49 books` book which was in pdf into multiple chapters, and the content of each chapter is stored in a DB as a nvarchar (max). One row per chapter.

Altogether there are `521 chapters`. All of those contents are in Hindi.

But the book could be up to 700+, and the chapter will also increase.

When I run this query over the content of a chapter, it returns the value as `49422`

```
select avg(leng)
from (
    select len(Text) as leng
    FROM [BookStoreDb].[dbo].[ChapterContent]
) as Total
```

But the main problem now arises.

When I tried to search for a string over all those content using this query,

```
  SELECT *
  FROM [BookStoreDb].[dbo].[ChapterContent]
  where Text like N'%प्रेम%'
```

It took almost 18min but Still I am not able to get any records. This seems too slow for the application.

So, I am quite stuck in the search. What did I do wrong? How should I approach this problem?

I had expected a search for at least 3-4 secs.

How could I handle this record properly?

**Edit After creating a full text index**

I created an index on the table, with the following command.

```
CREATE FULLTEXT CATALOG ftCatalog AS DEFAULT;


CREATE UNIQUE INDEX cont on dbo.ChapterContent(id)

CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX ON dbo.ChapterContent
(
    [Text]
    Language 1081
) KEY INDEX cont ON ftCatalog;
```

And run the query against the DB. The query is still slow, and it took forever but not a single piece of data was returned.

```
SELECT [Text]  
FROM dbo.ChapterContent   
WHERE FREETEXT([Text], 'प्रेम');
```

[image]

Comment: A `LIKE` is the *wrong* tool for this. I suspect a Full text index or perhaps Elastisearch would both be better options.

Comment: lucene does exactly what you describe. Its a search engine. https://github.com/apache/lucenenet

Comment: so the way I am storing my content in the database is okay?  except for the search?

Comment: I don't see what this has to do with c#

Comment: For why it didn't return data, I would look and make sure you are using the correct `Collation`. Options for speeding up search: 1) store book text in multiple columns (ex. 5 columns of nvarchar(1000)). Then you can add Indexes for each column. 2) Don't use SQL to search your text. Get the full dataset, and process data client side. 3) add a search engine

Comment: @thewallrus how would a document database help? Document doesn't mean "file". Without a full text search engine like Lucene, Elastic or SQL Server's Full Text Search, MongoDB is as slow as any other database. None of the other claims is valid either. `Get the full dataset, and process data client side.` why would an underpowered, memory-limited client machine run faster than a beefy database with full indexing supprot? Especially once you account for the network transfer time?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos thanks, yea i agree. i changed the comment

Comment: SQL Server has [full text search](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/search/full-text-search?view=sql-server-ver16) features that could help with this and search for words, variants of words or phrases. `like N'%प्रेम%'` can't take advantage of any indexes and has to scan the entire table to find matches. An FTS engine/index on the other hand shreds fields/documents, extracts and stems words and their relations in a text.

Comment: @thewallrus the other two points are equally bad

Comment: It seem kinda slow. Can you try reading whole book into your application memory and then just do a regular string matching? I'm not sure what kind of books you're storing but unless it's a lot of bibles i doubt it will be that much data

Comment: @siggemannen that's the absolute slowest way to do this. Not only is this a brute force approach as slow as LIKE, the client will be a low slower, with less RAM and slower disks than the server. Never mind transferring the data over the network

Comment: It's a commentary a transcribed speech into a book. Series-wise commentary.

Comment: When you use `WHERE CONTAINS(candidate_resume, '"SQL Server"')` the database will look into its FTS index to find which rows have texts that reference those words. `WHERE CONTAINS (Comments, 'FORMSOF(INFLECTIONAL, "drive")')` will match "drive," "drives," "drove," "driving," and "driven," [Query with Full Text Search](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/search/query-with-full-text-search?view=sql-server-ver16) shows the options

Comment: if that would be in English `will match "drive," "drives," "drove," "driving,"` would be also helpful, can it works similarly to the words of other languages too?

Comment: Yes, you can specify language-specific rules for stemming too. In the [Getting Started](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/search/get-started-with-full-text-search?view=sql-server-ver16) article, an index is created specifically for British English

Comment: @Larnu Used the full-text search too. But no luck!